# Spring 3.2 upgrade to 4.3 getting BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException

Tags: java, spring, java-8, autowired

I am in the process of a spring 3.2 to 4.3 upgrade and have encountered an issue injection dependencies.  We are also moving from Java 7 to 8 with this work.  I mention this as I am not sure if this is a spring issue or java 8 issue.

We have a class that extends org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices, which implements the org.springframework.security.web.authentication.RememberMeServices interface.  The bean definition looks like this:

```
<bean id="myRememberMeServices" class="com.mycompany.spring.security.services.impl.MyRememberMeServices">
            ...
    </bean>
```

The class looks like this:

```
public class MyRememberMeServices extends AbstractRememberMeServices implements CompanyRememberMeServices {
...
}
```

This is being injected to another class like this:

```
public class MyLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myRememberMeServices")
    private RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;
    ...
}
```

With spring 3.2 this is working fine.  With spring 4.3 I am getting a no qualifying bean exception during startup.  So it's not finding any candidate beans.  After much head banging and googling, I changed the @Autowired to @Resource to inject specifically by name as the @Qualifier does not help when no type match is found.  When I changed to @Resource I get the following exception:

> Error creating bean with name 'com.mycompany.spring.security.web.hand
>   lers.MyLogoutSuccessHandler#414fd67c': Injection of resource
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.Be anNotOfRequiredTypeException:
>   Bean named 'myRememberMeServices' is expected to be of type
>   [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Rem emberMeServices]
>   but was actually of type
>   [com.mycompany.spring.security.services.impl.MyRememberMeServices]

If I change my code to use the concrete type, MyRememberMeServices, the bean injection works.  What I don't understand is why I am unable to inject to the interface type of RememberMeServices since my class implements the RememberMeServices interface through the AbstractRememberMeServices?  Also this works in spring 3.2 (java 7)

I have read through the spring framework reference and a bunch of other posts and docs and have not found anything that would explain what changed between spring 3.2 and 4.3 that would prevent the inject to an interface.
    ...

Update:

It appears I was able to unravel this mystery, at least I believe I have, as
to why the dependency injection was failing.  I was inspired, as well as at my wits end, when I stumbled across another post talking about a conversion failure which appeared similar in nature to the issue I am having:
[Initialization of bean failed; ConversionNotSupportedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33501165/initialization-of-bean-failed-conversionnotsupportedexception)

To recap, I worked around the original error I posted by doing the following:

```
...
private RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;

@Resource
public void setRememberMeServices(MyRememberMeServices myRememberMeServices) {
    this.rememberMeServices = myRememberMeServices;
}
```

This resolved the original error because I injected using a setter method of
the concrete type MyRememberMeServices, and then just set it to the interface
type of RememberMeServices which Spring was complaining about.  As soon as this error was was fixed I got another dependency injection error saying:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultS
ecurityFilterChain#5': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7d884002' of type [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter] while set
ting constructor argument with key [6]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name '(inner bean)#7d884002': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException
: Failed to convert property value of type [com.mycompany.spring.security.web.handlers.MyAccessDeniedHandler] to required type [org.springf
ramework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler] for property 'accessDeniedHandler'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: C
annot convert value of type [com.mycompany.spring.security.web.handlers.MyAccessDeniedHandler] to required type [org.springframework.securi
ty.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler] for property 'accessDeniedHandler': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Which again is strange since the class in question is defined as:

```
public class MyAccessDeniedHandler extends AccessDeniedHandlerImpl {
...
}
```

After reading the above referenced post I decided to examine the classpath
in more detail and what I discovered is that we had 2 spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar's in play.

One jar is being loaded from /WEB-INF/lib and the other from /myproject/lib.
The jar in the /WEB-INF/lib folder is pulled in using maven during our build
using the following pom snip-it:

```
<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <springframework.security.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</springframework.security.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

However the spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar in /myproject/lib is part
of a common framework we are using and is not pulled in via maven.  It's just
there as part of the framework, if you will.  The jar's are the same version,
and as fare as I know the same.  Anyway, during java compile our code is compiled against /myproject/libs/spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar but during runtime the /WEB-INF/libs/spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar is higher in the classpath.  What I decided to do is remove the /WEB-INF/libs/spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar to see what happens.  Surprise surprise, all the dependencies injected. What the heck?

It seems that the /WEB-INF/libs/spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar somehow
causes Spring to think the the classes are not the same as what's in
/myproject/libs/spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar and therefore would give various errors about no matching bean or type's don't match when trying to resolve the dependencies.

Now this part is all conjecture and to be honest I am not sure if this is a Spring issue or a Java 8 thing.  What appears to have been happening is when my code was compiled it used the jar /myproject/libs/spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar.  The interface we are extending exists in this jar.

```
Example:
public class MyAccessDeniedHandler extends AccessDeniedHandlerImpl {
...
}
```

Where AccessDeniedHandlerImpl is in /myproject/libs/spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar.  During startup, e.g. runtime, Spring is using /WEB-INF/libs/spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar and looking for a matching bean for the type AccessDeniedHandler.  In this case
spring does not find an AccessDeniedHandler of type /WEB-INF/libs/spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar because the MyAccessDeniedHandler is of type /myproject/libs/spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar.
(I know these are not "types" but I am using this to illustrate the idea)

For whatever reason Spring or Java 8 looks at the object / object hierarchy and concluded that the AccessDeniedHander in /myproject/libs/spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar is not the same as the AccessDeniedHandler in /WEB-INF/libs/spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar and therefore failed to resolve the dependency.

The fix, in my case, was to remove this jar from the /WEB-INF/libs folder.

I would love to hear others opinion on this, or maybe someone can explain what is truly going on here.